# unwanted values returning in Freemarker iterating maps

Tags: java, freemarker

When iterating map

`<#list map?keys as key>
${key}
</#list>`

will return clone,1,getKey,5,etc

Anyone have solution instead of removing unwanted value one by one ?

Comment: What is the data in the map? What are you expecting to get? Your question doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: i had only 1,2,5 values but it gives others struff

Answer (score 4):

You get both methods and keys mixed, if I understand well. This depends on the `object_wrapper` configuration setting (`Configuration.setObjectWrapper(ObjectWrapper)`). If you are using a `BeansWrapper` as the `object_wrapper` (as opposed to `DefaultObjectWrapper`, which never had this problem), this can be prevented by `yourBeansWrapper.setSimpleMapWrapper(true)`. However, it's maybe not accidental that in that project it's `false`. There's a problem that FreeMarker language doesn't have a map type. It has something called hash, and that only supports string keys (sub-variables). So people may just use the Java API of `java.util.Map`-s instead of hash operators like `[]`, `?keys`, etc., and for that `setSimpleMapWrapper(false)` is needed, otherwise you don't see the `Map` methods. Then you should write `map.keySet()`.

**Update:** In 2.3.22 and later, nobody is forced to use mixed methods and keys anymore (which was a rather confusing workaround even back then), as the Java methods (and Java Bean properties) are accessible in a separate namespace through `?api`, like `myMap?api.get(nonStringKey)`, `myMap?api.keySet()` etc. So you can use an `ObjectWrapper` that exposes the `Map` keys only and supports the `?api` feature (preferably `object_wrapper=DefaultObjectWrapper(2.3.22)`), enable `?api` (`api_builtin_enabled=true`; by default it's disallowed for backward-security), then just use `?api` when you need something from the Java API namespace, and otherwise use `[]`, `?keys`, etc. if your `Map` keys are `String`-s.

Comment: You are supposed to Accept the answer then BTW.

Comment: @Nunien: If `map.keySet()` works for you, that means that `?keys`, `[]`, etc. sees this mess that the OP has faced with. See update above; people should and now always can avoid  the mixed-keys-and-members setup.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below syntax

```
<#assign keys = map?keys>
<#list keys as key>${key} = ${h[key]}; </#list>
```

[See the link](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html)

**EDIT -Extending @ddekany answer,**

you would need to  handle this in the code where you parse/invoke the FTL, some thing like below( just sample code). It could have been better ff you can add the FTL processing code here.

```
 BeansWrapper ow = new BeansWrapper();
  ow.setExposeFields(true);
 // ow.setSimpleMapWrapper(true);

  Template template = freeMarkerConfiguration.getTemplate(templateName, locale);
  template.setObjectWrapper(ow);
  template.process(root, writer);
```

Comment: @ddekany,+1, my answer doesn't make sense. I am withdrawing it. And your solution stands good, I understand BeansWrapper instance would have been configured incompletely, and is the reason for methods are also the items of the Map ,

Comment: Thank for solution. But your answer not solved my problem. Once i set

Comment: It's not a good idea to create new `BeansWrapper` for each template invocations because then `BeansWrapper` always starts with an empty introspection cache. So even when setting the `ObjectWrapper` globally (i.e., in `Configuration`) is not feasible for some reason, one should try to reuse the `BeansWrapper` instance.

Comment: An addition to my above comment: Starting from 2.3.21, `BeansWrapper`-s can be created with `BeansWrapperBuilder`, and those will often reuse/share the introspection cache with other similarly created `BeansWrapper`-s. (Furthermore, the `BeansWrapper` returned is possibly a reused singleton.)